# Invalid argument in sendfile() with two regular files

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, sendfile

I'm trying to test the `sendfile()` system call under Linux 2.6.32 to zero-copy data between two regular files.
As far as I understand, it should work: ever since 2.6.22, `sendfile()` has been implemented using `splice()`, and both the input file and the output file can be either regular files or sockets.

The following is the content of `sendfile_test.c`:

```
#include <sys/sendfile.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int result;
  int in_file;
  int out_file;

  in_file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  out_file = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);

  result = sendfile(out_file, in_file, NULL, 1);
  if (result == -1)
    perror("sendfile");

  close(in_file);
  close(out_file);

  return 0;
}
```

And when I'm running the following commands:

```
$ gcc sendfile_test.c 
$ ./a.out infile outfile
```

The output is

```
sendfile: Invalid argument
```

And when running

```
$ strace ./a.out infile outfile
```

The output contains

```
open("infile", O_RDONLY)                = 3
open("outfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 4
sendfile(4, 3, NULL, 1)                 = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, check that your open() calls don't return errors.

Comment: I fixed the command line input to what I originally intended.
Now you can see the resulting error in strace:
sendfile(4, 3, NULL, 1)                 = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)

Comment: And regarding the fact that sendfile() can get either a regular file or a socket on both ends: splice() must have a pipe as one of its arguments, but the current implementation of sendfile() allocates a temporary pipe buffer in the pipe cache, and splices the data to it from the input file, and then from it to the output file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to check that `argc` is equal to `3`, i.e. you are opening the output file by the name `argv[2]` but only give your program one argument (and you are not checking for errors after `open(2)`.)

You can use [`strace(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find out which system call fails.

#### Edit:

This looks like older kernel to me. Same source (modulo error checking) works fine here under  `2.6.33.4 #3 SMP`. Also, any particular reason you are copying just one byte?

```
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int in_file, out_file;

    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "usage: %s <in-file> <out-file>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if (( in_file = open( argv[1], O_RDONLY )) == -1 ) err( 1, "open" );
    if (( out_file = open( argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 )) == -1 )
        err( 1, "open(2)" );

    if ( sendfile( out_file, in_file, NULL, 4096 ) == -1 ) err( 1, "sendfile" );

    exit( 0 );
}
```

Trace:

```
nickf@slack:~/csource/linux/splice$ cc -Wall -pedantic -ggdb -g3 -o sf sndf.c 
nickf@slack:~/csource/linux/splice$ strace ./sf Makefile mm
...
open("Makefile", O_RDONLY)              = 3
open("mm", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 4
sendfile(4, 3, NULL, 4096)              = 239
exit_group(0)                           = ?
nickf@slack:~/csource/linux/splice$ diff Makefile mm 
nickf@slack:~/csource/linux/splice$
```

Comment: Right, sorry! I did this right before (passing two filenames). I just messed it up before copying it here.
I fixed my question.

Comment: Yup. Pasting the output in my question.

Comment: How odd, it seems I'm running an old kernel indeed!
I guess I should have mentioned I'm running this on Ubuntu:
2.6.32-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP.
I didn't imagine it should be different from the latest kernel, sendfile-wise.
I'm going to test this on a compiled kernel too.

Comment: And you're right. Running this on a 2.6.33.3 #1 SMP was successful.
Thanks!